# Display images when they are fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I want the image to be displayed only after it's fully loaded. How can I do that?

```
<ul id="listcontainer">
    <li class="li1">
        <img src="images/m1.png">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .li1 > img{width:100%;}

Comment: you can google for instance

Comment: http://bit.ly/1Xt9pNg

Answer (score 2):

You could play with the document.ready and window.load events as window.load fires when all your images are loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hide();
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $("img").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this
Put this in your css `#listcontainer{ opacity:0; }`

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#listcontainer').animate({
    opacity: '1'
    },500);
});
```

If you really want to hide the images you could use .css and display:none;
Put this in your css `#listcontainer{ display:none; }`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#listcontainer').css(
        'display', 'block'
        );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

```
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "images/m1.png";
            var src = document.getElementsByClassName("li1");
            src.appendChild(img);
        }, false);
    </script>
```